# How do I declare a dependency on jboss in SBT?

Tags: maven-2, sbt, jboss5.x, ivy, dependency-management

I have a project that depends on JBoss(specifically 5.1.0.GA) and I was playing around with trying to set this project up using SBT. What I was wondering is if there is a way to say "this project depends on JBoss version X and everything that goes with it" or do I have do declare every single dependency individually? My hope is that SBT will then download all the appropriate dependencies needed to compile the project.

I am pretty new to dependency management so any direction is appreciated. I am trying to do this using SBT (which uses Ivy) but an example in maven is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare every dependency manually, there is no super-pom, that includes all dependencies.

This is mostly very tricky, because it is hard to find out, what you need exactly in some cases.

A good start is to take every lib, that is also under jboss_home/lib and start reducing from there.

If you have your own repository proxy (like artifactory or archiva), you could create such a super pom.

This is from my own repository and might help getting you started. But this is in no way official and fitted to my needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.jayasoft.fr/org/ivyrep/ivy-doc.xsl"?>
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info 
        organisation="jboss"
        module="jboss"
        revision="5.1.0"
        status="release"
        publication="20110801120000"/>
    <configurations>
            <conf name="compile" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="client" visibility="public" extends="compile,mail,activation, aop"/>
            <conf name="server" visibility="public" extends="compile,servlet,jmx"/>
            <conf name="hibernate" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="activation" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="mail" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="servlet" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="jmx" visibility="public" />
                    <conf name="jmx-client" visibility="public" extends="client,jmx"/>
            <conf name="aop" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="javaee" visibility="public" />
            <conf name="ant" visibility="public" />
      <conf name="logging" visibility="public" />
    </configurations>
    <publications>
    <!-- from jbossall-client readme.txt -->
            <artifact name="commons-logging"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="concurrent"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="ejb3-persistence"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-aop-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-appclient"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-aspect-jdk50-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-client"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-common-core"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-common-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-core-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-proxy-impl-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-proxy-spi-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-security-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-j2se"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-javaee"      type="jar" conf="client,javaee,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-logging-log4j"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-logging-spi"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-messaging-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-remoting"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-security-spi"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-serialization"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-system-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-system-jmx-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jbosssx-as-client"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jbosssx-client"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jmx-client"      type="jar" conf="client,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jnp-client"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-mdr"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <!--END from  jbossall-client readme.txt -->
        <!-- additional client-libs -->
        <artifact name="jbosscache-core"        type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="trove"      type="jar" conf="client"/>
        <artifact name="javassist"      type="jar" conf="client,hibernate"/>
        <!-- END additional client-libs -->
        <artifact name="activation"         type="jar" conf="activation"/>
        <artifact name="mail"               type="jar" conf="mail"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-javaee"       type="jar" conf="compile"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-j2se"         type="jar" conf="compile"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-system-jmx"       type="jar" conf="compile,jmx"/>
        <artifact name="jbosscache-core"        type="jar" conf="compile"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-remoting"         type="jar" conf="compile,ant"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-kernel"       type="jar" conf="compile"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-logging-spi"      type="jar" conf="compile, logging"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-security-spi"         type="jar" conf="compile"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-ext-api"         type="jar" conf="server"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-ejb3-core"      type="jar" conf="server"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-integration"      type="jar" conf="compile,ant"/>
        <artifact name="ejb3-persistence"   type="jar" conf="hibernate"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-core"         type="jar" conf="hibernate"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-entitymanager" type="jar" conf="hibernate"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-annotations"  type="jar" conf="hibernate"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-commons-annotations"  type="jar" conf="hibernate"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-system-client"    type="jar" conf="server"/>
        <artifact name="servlet-api"        type="jar" conf="servlet"/>
        <artifact name="jbosssx"            type="jar" conf="server"/>
        <artifact name="jmx-invoker-adaptor-client"     type="jar" conf="server,jmx,ant"/>
        <artifact name="antlr"  type="jar" conf="hibernate"/>       
        <artifact name="slf4j-api"  type="jar" conf="server, logging"/>
        <artifact name="slf4j-jboss-logging"    type="jar" conf="server, logging"/>
        <artifact name="jboss-aop-client"  type="jar" conf="aop"/>
        <artifact name="jbossjmx-ant"  type="jar" conf="ant"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```